# GCP Firewall allow ingress traffic based on domain name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall

Is GCP Firewall able to allow ingress traffic based on a specific domain name?

I've googled about it and I didn't find any result on this.

All I know is it can allow or deny based on IP address.

Comment: Packets do not arrive with a "domain name" to filter on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A network [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) typically acts at the packet level and since network packets don't carry information about the domain, the standard GCP [VPC Firewall](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) will not let you do that.

What you are looking for is an Application Firewall (or Layer 7 Firewall). Google Cloud has another service called [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/understanding-google-cloud-armors-new-waf-capabilities) that has WAF (Web Application Firewall) capabilities. I think that by using Cloud Armor and load balancers you might be able to do what you want.

Comment: Can you please point to a sample rule in cloud armor ?